# Adding a php variable to an onclick event

Tags: php, onclick

This is going to be so simple but I can't see it for looking!!

I have an onclick link on a div, which needs to link to a php file with a parameter 'key=...' The problem with what I've written is that the key number is not being passed.... Am I missing something with my quotes?

```
<div class="footer-button" onclick="location.href='functions/images-delete.php?key=<?php echo $row_images['key']?>';">
  Yes
  </div>
```

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like...?

Comment: I get taken to the link but without the key number.... ie. functions/images-delete.php?key=

Comment: Looks like `$row_images['key']` doesn't exist/is empty then.

Comment: Thanks deceze - sounds simple when you say it like that, but you were right, I'd placed it outside a repeat region... sometimes you just need someone to state the obvious! Ta

Comment: Activate error reporting, it should have helped you notice missing variables!